# Retrieve current environment in code (Kotlin, Docker)

Tags: docker, kotlin

I would like to retrieve info about where the application is running.

So let's say I have a DEV and PROD environment. In my code, I would like to retrieve the link of the environment, where the application is running, e.g.:

- if in DEV environment: `https://dev.mycompany.com/myproduct/app`
- if in PROD environment: `https://mycompany.com/myproduct/app`

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass it as environment variable (e.g. `APP_ENV`) to you app and use `System.getenv("APP_ENV")` to access it. It's [one of the twelve-factor app best practices](https://12factor.net/config), btw.

The way you pass to you container differs depending on the way you start it.

### Docker run

Pass the variables [directly via `--env` / `-e` options for `docker run` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file), or store them in a file and pass the whole file via `--env-file`:

```sh
docker run -e VAR1 --env APP_ENV=dev --env-file ./env your_image:latest
```

### Docker compose

[Use `environment` or `env_file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables) (note that they set `NODE_ENV` variable in the docs, just like in your case!):

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: 'your_image:latest'
    env_file:
     - ./env
    environment:
     - APP_ENV=dev
```

### Kubernetes

[Use `env`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container):

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: your_app:latest
    env:
    - name: APP_ENV
      value: "dev"
```

In k8s you [can reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information) another values in environment variables, so the environment can be stored in the metadata.

---

There are, of course, other ways to provide values to the app, like:

- Code generation and build-time substitutions. It can be used to provide, for example, Git revision: the output of `git rev-parse` is just substituted somewhere in your code. Requires extra build configuration + you'll need different builds for different envs.
- Program arguments. It's as simple as running `app arg1 arg2 ... dev ... argn`. Pretty similar to environment variables, but, IMHO, has a flaw: program args are accessible only in your program's entry point (`main`), so you'll need to parse them and pass to the other parts of the app. I can be good for some dynamic inputs, but inconvenient for a static data, like app's environment.
- Vendor metadata, like EC2 [Instance Metadata and User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html). Requires specific APIs to access.

As you see none of them provides a combination of flexibility, ubiquity and simpleness of environment variables.